# mvc - Html.BeginForm postbacks to wrong controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.beginform

I'm facing a very annoying issue in my mvc 4 application.

What I'm doing:
I have a main view (Index) and a partial view added to main view. on partial view a form is added to post data to the action in some controller but, it posts to Home controller each time.

**Note:** both of the controllers are on root.

Here is how my code looks like:

form on partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchLaptop", "SearchControl", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
}
```

Action in SearchControl controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchLaptop()
{

}
```

but on clicking the button in form it never goes to the SearchControl controller but, goes to Home controller always.

i.e. the url is supposed to be:

> /SearchControl/SearchLaptop

but, it is always looks like:

> /Home/SearchLaptop

Can anyone please help in this regard. Thanks

Comment: Was the view initially rendered from `HomeController`? Most likely you have nested forms.

Comment: How does your routing look like?

Comment: Here is code on main view to render the partial view initially: @{Html.RenderAction("GetSearchControl", "SearchControl");}

Comment: Again, which controller generated the initial/main view?

Comment: Then you almost certainly have nested forms (which is invalid html). Edit your question to add the code for the main view

Comment: Kindly share your main controller's view code. It might contain another form tag.

Comment: There is only one form tag on my entire page.

Comment: Are you saying you have a form tag in the main view (which means it may be invalid because you have a form tag in the partial as well). Show your code!

Comment: Well, there is nothing form like thing on main view. form is placed on partial only.

Comment: Please share below 3 codes: 1) route.config files routes 2) Main view code and 3) Partial view code. Which can help to understand your problem with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by moving partial view to Shared folder.